# Deploying a winForm C# application that uses a vc++ dll and this dll uses a shared library generated by matlab R2013a

Tags: dependencies, shared-libraries, setup-deployment, matlab-compiler

I’ve created a dll in MATLAB by using of following command:

```
mcc –B cpplib:mylib mylib.dll
```

and then I use this dll in a vc++ program that it also generates another dll.
Finally I’d like to use the latest generated dll in a winform c# application and deploy it.
In vc++ program, at first I must be used the following lines of code:

```
mclInitializeApplication(); //for initializing the application  
mylibInitialize(); //for initializing the library
```

When I build the source code in visual studio environment everything is ok but when I build in release mode and generate an installer with using of Advanced Installer and install this program in my system (that program is written in it!) `mclInitializeApplication()` always returns false and my program can’t continue.(I log each step to find the problem).
Could you help me to find my problem please?!

Comment: @jonskeet could you guid me at this problem please?